# How to configure send mail task dynamically in SSIS using Package Configuration

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a send mail task which sends the excel as attachment. We have couple of ids in CC, BCC and to. I want to configue send mail task dynamically using package configuration, So it takes all ids, message subject, and messageSourse dynamically. How to achieve this in SSIS?

And I have to configure that smtp connection also through package configuration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please look into it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075073/send-email-to-dynamic-recipient-ssis-send-mail-task

Answer (score 2):

Create variables for each aspect of the Mail task you would like configure, then map those variables to the various properties of the Mail task.

You will need another string variable for the SMTP server name, which gets mapped in the properties of the connection manager.

Once the variables are created and mapped, open the package configuration settings and map the variables to the package configuration.