# How do I send a record count of a flat file in an email in SSIS

Tags: email, ssis, rowcount, record-count

I have a .txt file being outputted from a marketing software that gets moved to an FTP folder every morning. I want to check if there is records being exported so I would like to send an email showing how many records were exported. How would I do that through SSIS?

Currently I have the file move task and email task set up. But I am unable to get the record count of the flat file and have it in an email.

Comment: Is the problem you don't know how to count the number of rows in a file or that you don't know how to make the body/subject an email dynamic?

Comment: I would say I have both those problems.

Comment: Seems like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file + https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/906547/how-to-create-a-dynamic-subject-or-message-for-the-send-mail-task-in-s  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075073/send-email-to-dynamic-recipient-ssis-send-mail-task/5076269 or Siva's extremely detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439663/how-to-send-the-records-from-a-table-in-an-e-mail-body-using-ssis-package would seem to solve your problems